# How to predict using ordered probit regression and calculate prediction accuracy?

Tags: prediction, accuracy, rms, ordered-probit

I want to do an [ordered probit regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_probit), then cross-validate model prediction accuracy with 80% data for training and 20% for validation, and calculate [RMSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation) for predictions.

Consider this dataset:

```
  X     Y
----------
 2.3    1
 3.1    2
 3.5    2
 10.0   5
 6.8    4
 5.0    3
 5.4    2
 3.2    1
```

I did this:

```
x=c(2.3,3.1,3.5,10.0,6.8,5.0,5.4,3.2)
y=c(1,2,2,5,4,3,2,1)
myData=data.frame(cbind(x,y))

library("MASS")
reg=polr(as.factor(myData$y)~myData$x,data=myData,method="probit")
```

I saw [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41006/predicting-ordered-logit-in-r), but I couldn't fully understand. Suppose `myValidationData` contains 20% of data which I want to use for validation. So, I would do:

```
fit=predict(reg,type="probs")
x=c(5.6, 5.1)
y=c(3,3)
myValidationData=data.frame(cbind(x,y))
```

This is how I tried to predict, but is it correct, when I want to cross-validate?

```
fit=predict(reg,data=myValidationData,type="probs")
```

How should I measure RMSE? And, how can I plot the prediction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The R `rms` package has many capabilities for validating ordinal regression models.  Start with the `orm` function.  Note that split-sample validation takes an extremely large sample size to work.  You might be better off with bootstrap validate as implemented in the `rms` `validate` and `calibrate` functions.

Measures of predictive accuracy for ordinal $Y$ include

- Generalized $c$-index (generalized ROC area) from Somers' $D_{xy}$ rank correlation
- Spearman $\rho$
- Other rank correlation measures - these are all measures of pure predictive discrimination
- Generalized $R^2$ based on model likelihood ratio $\chi^2$ statistic
- Calibration accuracy for $Prob(Y \geq y | X)$ using a nonparametric smooth calibration curve

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My actual data is about ~2000 elements for training and ~200 elements for validation, so I think it would be fine.

Comment: There is a fundamental problem: 
How can I calculate prediction accuracy on ordered categorical data?
http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174255/

Comment: That's what the answer above was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

That looks correct; note that after you make the myData data frame, you can use:

```
myData$y = factor(myData$y)
reg <- polr(y ~ x, data = myData, method = "probit")
```

Later, you can make the validation data with:

```
myValidationData <- data.frame(x = c(5.6, 5.1), y = c(3,3))
```

Your syntax works fine, I just thought this was a bit "cleaner".

Here's a great link on ordinal regression that includes syntax to plot the predicted values (it's actually about SEM with categorical variables, but there's a great section on ordinal regression in the middle):

http://www.personality-project.org/r/tutorials/summerschool.14/rosseel_sem_cat.pdf

I'm not sure how to measure the RMSE, but you should be able to use

```
(residuals(reg))
```

To get the model errors.

Comment: I get `NULL` when I invoke `(residuals(reg))`.

Comment: Hmmm, it looks like `polr()` doesn't supply a residuals object. In that case, try `predict(reg) - myData$y` to get the residuals (without a newdata argument, `predict()` uses the dataset used to fit the model).