# Ordered probit model prediction: why highest probabilities and not number of thresholds exceeded?

Tags: prediction, method-comparison, ordered-probit, polr

I'm running [ordered probit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_probit) regression models with `polr` in `R`.
[This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41006/predicting-ordered-logit-in-r) states that for prediction, `polr` returns the category with the highest probability for given $x$. I would have expected that the predicted category is equal to the number of estimated thresholds ($\hat{\zeta}$) exceeded by $x' \hat{\beta}$ (what imo would be in line with the model assumptions). Is there a reason, why the `polr`-approach is "better" then the thresholds-approach?